# Убрать элемент до перезагрузки страницы, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую! Нужно убрать элемент со страницы до её закрытия: юзер заходит, нажимает кнопу "не интересует", и до того как он закроет страницу и откроет её заново, элемент не показывается даже при перезагрузке страницы. Как это сделать, и возможно ли это сделать только с помощью javascript?

Comment: Нужно задействовать cookie или localstorage, записываете туда любую переменную допустим A после закрытия окна, присваеваете ей true, а в начале проверяете, равняется ли переменная из localstorage или cookie, true. И открываете в зависимости от этого значения окно или не открываете, дайте знать еслии нужны примеры кода.

Comment: Да правильно используйте cookie. Нету другой решение только если не пользователь, а гость

Answer (score 1):

Удалить элемент:

```
document.getElementById("my-element").remove();
```

Сделать невидимым:

```
document.getElementById("my-element").style.display = "none";
```

если нужно сохранить какую-то инфу то можно использовать не куки а 
[Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)